# test class code for inbound rest api

Tags: apex, unit-test

Apex

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/IntershopRelatedAccounts/*')
//beginning of 1
global class IntershopInboundRestTofetchContacts {
    @HttpGet
    global static void fetchRelatedAccountswithContacts(){
        String emailstr = RestContext.request.params.get('Email');


        // Search contacts 
        List<Contact> cont = [ Select Id, Name, Email,AccountId,Current_Employee__c,Ecommerce_User__c,MailingCountry  from Contact where Email=:emailstr ];

        // When  contact does not exists
        if(cont.size()==0){
           List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
           Email_Notify__c   emailaddress = Email_Notify__c.getValues('InboundEmailId');
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           sendTo.add(emailaddress.EmailId__c);
           email.setSubject('Regarding creation of Accounts and Contacts ');
           email.setToAddresses(sendTo);
           email.setPlainTextBody('kindly create accounts and contacts');
           Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

        }
```

Test class code:-

```
@isTest
public class Test_IntershopInboundRest {
    public static testMethod void Test_1(){


        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        // pass the req and resp objects to the method     
        req.requestURI = 'https://danaherlbs--test.cs86.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/IntershopRelatedAccounts?Email=vineet@gmail.com';  
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;
        string emailstr = req.params.get('Email');
        List<string> sendto = new List<string>();
        Account a= new Account();
        a.name='account';
        a.SAP_Account_Number__c='569';
        a.Inactive__c=false;
        insert a;
        contact c= new contact();
        c.LastName='james';
        c.AccountId=a.Id;
        c.MailingCountry ='India';
        c.Current_Employee__c=true;
        c.Ecommerce_User__c=false;
        c.Email='james@gmail.com';
        insert c;  
        List<Contact> conlst=[select id ,Email from contact where Email=:emailstr];  

        if(conlst.size()==0){   
            Email_Notify__c emailnotify = new Email_Notify__c();
            emailnotify.Name='james';
            emailnotify.EmailId__c='james@gmail.com';
            insert emailnotify;
            Email_Notify__c emailcustset=[select Id, EmailId__c from Email_Notify__c where Id=:emailnotify.Id]; 
            system.debug('11111'+emailcustset.EmailId__c);

            Test.startTest();


            IntershopInboundRestTofetchContacts.fetchRelatedAccountswithContacts();  


            Test.stopTest(); 
        }

    }
}
```

The code is failing at this line:
`sendTo.add(emailaddress.EmailId__c);`

Error:- Attempt to de-reference the null object.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @david The code is failing at this line:
sendTo.add(emailaddress.EmailId__c);

Error:- Attempt to de-reference the null object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like `Email_Notify__c` is a custom setting.

Custom settings are not available in unit tests (unless you use seeAllData = true, which is an almost universally bad idea).

Create an appropriate instance of `Email_Notify__c` in your unit test, and insert it. That should resolve this particular error.

+edit:
Ok, I'm a bit blind. After your comment stating that you solved the issue, I see that you are, in fact, creating and `Email_Notify__c` record in your test.

As you mentioned, that means that the `Name` field of the custom setting record you're creating ("James") does not match the name that you're expecting (which in this case is "InboundEmailId").

Since there was no custom setting record with Name = "InboundEmailId", `emailaddress` was initialized to null, and calling `null.<anything>` gives you the null pointer exception.

Altering the `Email_Notify__c` record that you're creating in your test to have its name set to "InboundEmailId" should resolve this issue (and it did, according to your comment).

Comment: yeah it is a custom setting. i have that value in databse.

Comment: @most_intelligent Read what I said again. Even if you have values for your custom setting, they are not available in unit tests. You need to insert values in your unit test just like you would for (most) SObjects.

Comment: i resolved the issue,  instead of  emailnotify.Name='james',it should be 
emailnotify.Name='inboundemailId'.

Comment: neways derek ,one more issue that how the code will go in the else part,i.e. when conlst.size()>1. ne idea?

Comment: @most_intelligent Generally speaking, we encourage people to create multiple questions rather than using the same one over and over. Begging specific people for help is quite rude. Your provided code contains no `else`. Also, please keep in mind that formatting your code so it is readable is appreciated (and makes it easier for other people to help you).

Comment: ...yeah i understood your point. actually this was really very frustrating thats y i needed help. really apologize for the issue. hope u can understand

Comment: @most_intelligent The general advice I give for testing is _"you only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of a test method"_. You need to set up the test environment (inserting custom settings, inserting SObjects, etc...) so that you guarantee that your various for loops and if/else statements will be run. In situations where 2 pieces of code are mutually exclusive (i.e. a single record will execute only one of the two pieces of code), then that's an indication that you should write an additional test method.

Comment: thnx for ur valuable inputs. that is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your test class executes in a context isolated from your database content, which *includes* your custom settings. You must construct and insert an `Email_Notify__c` instance in your test method or `@testSetup` method for it to be available in your test classes.

Since there is no `Email_Notify__c` available, `emailaddress` is null, and you get a null pointer exception. Since custom settings can be modified or removed in production, your code should check for `null` and handle it appropriately.

Comment: the value of custom setting is there in database

Comment: neways david,one more issue that how the code will go in the else part,i.e. when conlst.size()>1. ne idea?

Comment: Please don't use comment threads on (both of your) answers to ask follow-up questions. You can ask a new question if you need to, but please be specific and understand that you need to show your research effort - we can't write code for you.

Comment: really apologise for the inconveniences caused to u....ok let me put it as a seperate question.